# 12 undefined beings

Tags: cipher, wordplay

Round and round, pay attention to the count.
The words will serve as a guide to unveil who we are.

> A dirty creature who walks on all fours.
>
> Queen zebra
>
> White Light just had unbind
>
> Very enthusiastic four fowls make X
>
> 9 63 6 2 60 69
>
> Young to go quirky kicks
>
> Orange violet yellow zeal lime
>
> Apple pineapple mango mangosteen xigua
>
> Vulture xylophone width thing net hot
>
> Blob yell yall chocolate doe over black
>
> Over zealous rage
>
> Crouch very tight

Hint 1

> The first of each matters

Hint 2

> The 12 beings are related to each other

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> Animals of the Chinese Zodiac, in order starting from Rat

By line:
A dirty creature who walks on all fours.

> RAT; direct clue

Queen zebra

> OX; first letters are QZ, which is OX rot-2ed

White Light just had unbind

> TIGER; first letters are WLJHU, which is TIGER rot-3ed

Very enthusiastic four fowls make X

> RABBIT; first letters are VEFFMX, which is RABBIT rot-4ed

9 63 6 2 60 69

> DRAGON; these numbers are the A1Z26 encoding of 'DRAGON', with each digit rot-5ed over the digits 0-9 (D=4 -> 9, R=18 -> 63, A=1 -> 6, etc.)

Young to go quirky kicks

> SNAKE; first letters are YTGQK, which is SNAKE rot-6ed

Orange violet yellow zeal lime

> HORSE; first letters are OVYZL, which is HORSE rot-7ed

Apple pineapple mango mangosteen xigua

> SHEEP; first letters are APMMX, which is SHEEP rot-8ed

Vulture xylophone width thing net hot

> MONKEY; first letters are VXWTNH, which is MONKEY rot-9ed

Blob yell yall chocolate doe over black

> ROOSTER; first letters are BYYCDOB, which is ROOSTER rot-10ed

Over zealous rage

> DOG; first letters are OZR, which is DOG rot-11ed

Crouch very tight

> PIG; first letters are CVT, which is PIG rot-13ed (note rot-12 is skipped)

Comment: Your answers are right, the fifth one is also rot-5 but taken in another way.

Comment: Ah, now I see it; updating my answer with justification for the fifth line now.